# When I run iPhone app on iPad the screen resolution is wrong. How to fix this?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, retina-display

I encountered with a strange problem. I develop an application which is targeting iPhone device family with Retina 3.5 and 4. All the time I used iPhone 5 simulator to test all the UI and functionality and everything was good but know I have to test push notifications. I have iPad 4 (model MD522ZP/A) as an iOS 6 device. When I run my app on it all the UI layout became wrong. The most weird problem is when I tried to check display resolution with this code:

```
NSLog(@"RESOLUTION = %@", NSStringFromCGSize([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size));
```

I got this : `RESOLUTION = {320, 480}`. But it is iPhone 3 resolution! Why iPad didn't use Retina 3.5/4 resolution ? And how can I fix it? I don't want to create separate `xibs` only for iPad testing but I want to test my app on it so that all the UI elements will fit on screen.

Hope for the help.

Comment: "I don't want to create separate xibs only for iPad testing" - this is fundamentally wrong-headed. Running iPhone-only apps in scaled mode on the iPad is a crutch to allow older applications to run. Nobody should be developing *new* iOS apps that don't support iPad natively.

Comment: To run correctly you would have to create separate xibs/storyboard to ipad in your project. See this link, in Universal app section: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html , otherwise the ipad will keep simulating an iphone device

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not wrong. It is doing exactly the right thing. All references to sizes are in points, not pixels. When you get the bounds, it will be 320x480 on all 3.5" screens whether they are retina or not. Try it on any 3.5" retina device. You will get the same log output.

The iPad does not emulate a 4" device when running an iPhone-only app. It will always be a 3.5" iPhone compatible mode.

So seeing 320x480 is the correct size to expect.

Think of it this way. A retina iPad will show an iPhone-only app like it is running on a 3.5" retina iPhone. A non-retina iPad will show an iPhone-only app like it is running on a 3.5" non-retina iPhone.

Comment: "It will always be a 3.5" iPhone compatible mode." Forever? 3.5" should become obsolete soon for this purpose, re 6 and 6 plus.  New iPhone apps might reasonably expect at least 4" and be ugly when scrunched into 3.5".

Comment: @vonlost The question was about running an iPhone-only app on iPads, not the latest iPhones (more than a year after the question was asked). New iPhone apps can still be run on 3.5" iPhones. You need to code for that so they are not ugly.

Comment: It's the same issue, that time marches on, and we can't fully take advantage of iPhone 5/6 real estate, doing things not possible in 3.5".  I'm happy to give up sales on the 4 to get an app that can work only on the 5 and 6. I'm already restricted to iOS 7+, not a problem. But it's especially a waste on iPad, where so much space is available.