# Xcode app shows in 3.5 inch in an Ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've created an app, target iOS 8, it works fine on simulator, iphone 4, iphone 5s, but when i test it on an iPad, the app shows on iphone 4 format..

The app does not support ipad. Just wondering why it doesnt show 4 Inch on an iPad.

Any ideas why it does that?

Comment: Please check your build setting. Make the app universal (both iPad and iPhone) compatible.

Comment: so you want to know the reason or want to show specific size in iPad?

Comment: I don't want to support ipad. But some users will download the app on ipad even though the app isn't available on ipad. if they do, i dont want them to see it on a 3.5 inch screen, but 4 inch.

Comment: If you don't support iPad devices, your app will always be shown as a 3.5 inch device, like i've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build setting. Make the app universal (both iPad and iPhone) compatible.
Here is an screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the default (and the only one, i think) behavior for running iPhone-only, not universal, apps on iPad.

Hope it helps.

PS: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046374/3996954) for another question explain a bit more.