# iPad running iPhone app - Which version?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, retina-display, autoscalemode

If an iPhone app is installed onto an iPad what version of the iPhone app is run? (for auto scaling purposes).

I only have access to an iPad Mini and it appears to display the iPhone 4 version of the app.
However in a week I have a showcase where the app will be displayed on iPad 3rd and 4th gens.

Will the app run at iPhone 4 resolution on these iPads as well?

Cheers,
Chok

Comment: this post can help:[When I run iPhone app on iPad][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046285/when-i-run-iphone-app-on-ipad-the-screen-resolution-is-wrong-how-to-fix-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

A retina iPad will show an iPhone-only app like it is running on a 3.5" retina iPhone. A non-retina iPad will show an iPhone-only app like it is running on a 3.5" non-retina iPhone.

You can Check the resolution while running on iOS app with Log

```
  NSLog(@"RESOLUTION = %@", NSStringFromCGSize([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size));
```

> RESOLUTION = {320, 480}

for more details about this :[Please refer this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046285/when-i-run-iphone-app-on-ipad-the-screen-resolution-is-wrong-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: Perfect answer :) Thank you